# How To Change SCSS Variable in Angular

Tags: angular

There is a variable in my scss

```
$primary: red !default;
```

I have to change this variable dynamically.

I created a function my component.ts

```
changeColor(newColor) {  }
```

İs that possible to change color in function? How can i reach to the scss variable? If you help me i will be glad.

Answer (score 5):

You won't be able to do that as SCSS gets compiled into CSS.
What you can do instead is rely on CSS custom properties aka CSS Variables.

Either completely rely on CSS variables or you can assign a CSS variable to your SCSS variable like so:

```
:root {
  --primary: #0070f3;
}

$primary: var(--primary);

.main {
  color: $primary;
}
```

You can then change the CSS Variable in JavaScript:

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--primary', 'red');
```